# Calculating the probability of getting the lowest card in a circle of cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Assume there is a circle of N persons, and each one gets a random card with a number between 1 and N (all different), faced down.

They all flip their cards at the **same time**.

What is the probability of one individual having the minimum card between himself, and his two direct neighbors?

One way I thought of was that it is the multiplication of the probability I get the lower card than my left neighbor AND the lower than my right neighbor, which calculates as 1/2 * 1/2 = 1/4.

The other way to think about it is having 3 different ranges for my card to be: the highest, the median, and the lowest. All symmetric so the probability is 1/3.

I know the answer should be 1/3, so could you explain why is the first approach wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: You can only multiply probabilities when events are independent. If your card is lower than that of your left neighbor, that increases the probability that it's also lower than that of your right neighbor.

Comment: You need $N\ge 3$.  The first approach is wrong because if you have a lower card than your neighbour on your left, so are more likely to have a low card, and this affects the conditional probability you have a lower card than your neighbour on your right.  They are not independent events so you cannot multiply the marginal probabilities

Comment: There is no independence. The fact that my card lower than my left neighbour already indicates in a sense that my card is probably not so high. Under that condition it will actually have probability 2/3 to be less than the card of my right neighbour as well.